# Binding Json to Kendo UI Web Scheduler does not work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I am using ASP.NET MVC with KENDO UI Scheduler control.

here is my data binding

```
                   dataSource: {
                        batch: true,
                        transport: {
                            read: {
                                url: "/scheduling/GetAllAppointments",
                                dataType: "json"
                            }


                        },
                        schema: {
                            model: {
                                id: "AppointmentId",
                                fields: {
                                    taskID: { from: "AppointmentId", type: "number" },
                                    title: { from: "Title", defaultValue: "No title", validation: { required: true } },
                                    start: { type: "date", from: "StartDateTime" },
                                    end: { type: "date", from: "EndDateTime" },
                                    description: { from: "Description" },
                                    ownerId: { from: "CustomerId", defaultValue: 1 },
                                    isAllDay: { type: "boolean", from: "IsAllDay" }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

All fields from JSON properly mapped to Schema property of Kendo Ui.
But data is not rendering.

here is my json returned from controller

```
       {"AppointmentId":2,"CalendarId":0,"CustomerId":1,"AppointmentDate":"\/Date(1409239020000)\/","StartDateTime":"\/Date(1409239020000)\/","EndDateTime":"\/Date(1409243400000)\/","AppointmentTypeId":0,"AppointmentStatusId":0,"CreatedDate":"\/Date(1408634331134)\/","CreatedBy":1,"LastModifiedDate":null,"LastModifiedBy":null,"Title":"Raju appointment","Description":"appointment","IsAllDay":false,"ReservationNumber":null,"RecurrenceRule":null,"RecurrenceID":null,"RecurrenceException":null,"AppointmentSystemStatusId":1,"Customer":null,"CustomerVehicle":null,"AllCustomers":null,"User":null,"User1":null,"AppointmentAttributes":null,"AppointmentAudits":null,"AppointmentNotifications":null,"AppointmentResources":null}]
```

here is my controller code

```
   public JsonResult GetAllAppointments()
    {
        IEnumerable<AppointmentModel> appointmentCollection = app_repository.GetAll();
        if (appointmentCollection == null)
        {
            return Json(appointmentCollection, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        return Json(appointmentCollection, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Any date format issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to bind to the same data using this code:

```
  <div id="scheduler"></div>
  <script>
    $("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
      date: new Date("2014/8/28"),
      startTime: new Date("2014/8/28 10:00 am"),
      dataSource: {
        data: [ {"AppointmentId":2,"CalendarId":0,"CustomerId":1,"AppointmentDate":"\/Date(1409239020000)\/","StartDateTime":"\/Date(1409239020000)\/","EndDateTime":"\/Date(1409243400000)\/","AppointmentTypeId":0,"AppointmentStatusId":0,"CreatedDate":"\/Date(1408634331134)\/","CreatedBy":1,"LastModifiedDate":null,"LastModifiedBy":null,"Title":"Raju appointment","Description":"appointment","IsAllDay":false,"ReservationNumber":null,"RecurrenceRule":null,"RecurrenceID":null,"RecurrenceException":null,"AppointmentSystemStatusId":1,"Customer":null,"CustomerVehicle":null,"AllCustomers":null,"User":null,"User1":null,"AppointmentAttributes":null,"AppointmentAudits":null,"AppointmentNotifications":null,"AppointmentResources":null}],
        schema: {
        model: {
            id: "AppointmentId",
            fields: {
                taskID: { from: "AppointmentId", type: "number" },
                title: { from: "Title", defaultValue: "No title", validation: { required: true } },
                start: { type: "date", from: "StartDateTime" },
                end: { type: "date", from: "EndDateTime" },
                description: { from: "Description" },
                ownerId: { from: "CustomerId", defaultValue: 1 },
                isAllDay: { type: "boolean", from: "IsAllDay" }
            }
        }
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
```

The event was properly displayed. [Here](http://dojo.telerik.com/iLojo) is a live demo.

Comment: Thanks Atanas, can u help me here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25479836/how-to-prevent-kendo-ui-shceduler-event-popup-and-show-it-in-same-page

Comment: @Atanas can you give me the idea what is the solution when i used static data then its work and when come from controller action then not working.